# Octree to Quadtree from Octomap

Tags: ros, octomap, octomap-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
I am using Octomapping in ROS to generate an occupancy grid but I want to use it for 2d Navigation so is there a possibility to convert the optimized Octree to a Quadtree ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217385/octree-to-quadtree-from-octomap/) by [ktiwari9](https://answers.ros.org/users/18753/ktiwari9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2015-09-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, it is not really converting it to a Quadtree.
But as you are using ROS for 2D navigation, you should be able to use the `ocotmap_server_multilayer` [(LINK)](http://wiki.ros.org/octomap_server#octomap_server_multilayer) which publishes multilayered `nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid`s. Check out the [`3d_navigation`](http://wiki.ros.org/3d_navigation) for a demo video.

Having a quick look at the [source code](https://github.com/OctoMap/octomap_mapping/blob/indigo-devel/octomap_server/src/OctomapServerMultilayer.cpp), I'd say that you would have to adjust it a bit.

Maybe, using the downprojected map of the `octomap_server` is already enough for you, but I had problems with this (too much clutter)...

If there are better ways, I'd be happy to know as well ;-)

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jwlifly](https://answers.ros.org/users/23286/jwlifly/) on 2016-05-03**:
hi, i came across the same problem, but after i modify the octomap_server_multilayer.cpp(/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/octomap_mapping), how do i rebuild the file to make the system know that the file has been changed? I tried rosmake, but i didn't work?  Any suggestion? Thank you

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-05-03**:
Check out the source code into a catkin workspace. You should never manually change any files int `/opt/...`.

FYI, the current ROS LTS release is indigo (two releases ahead of groovy), and the next release, kinetic (four ahead) just reached beta. You should probably change to a newer release..

**Comment by [jwlifly](https://answers.ros.org/users/23286/jwlifly/) on 2016-05-03**:
I have worked it out. Thanks.